# My Expo stuck at splash screen after building it for android

Tags: android, react-native, build, apk, expo-go

I have used eas buidl -p android --profile preview to build my .apk file. But I am not getting why app is stuck at Splash Screen. I am not getting what is the cause. Please help me out and thank you in advance.

my pcakage.json

````
  "name": "appName-mob",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build": "eas build -p android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.3.9",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-view-more-text": "^2.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "private": true
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time. But this problem has been solved. Actually it wasn't a problem in the development server. So, I made a development build and ran my code there and got the log of UIManager Issue which was then resolved by installing react-native-screens. I would suggest if this happen to any of you again just make a development build and test your code there. It was very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

in development mode clear application cache and storage then test your app

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried this and this solved one of mine another problem lol.